# Error: Function Claims that it does not Return Anything

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created this function using dart and the flutter framework that returns a widget:

```
Widget adjustImage(String weatherPicture, int day) {
    if (weatherPicture == 'images/01n.png' || weatherPicture == 'images/13d.png' || weatherPicture == 'images/13n.png') {
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            '${giveWeekday(convertEpochToDate(forecastDay[day]))}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 17.0,
            ),
          ),
          Image.asset(
            weatherPicture,
            width: 15.0,
            height: 15.0,
          ),
          Text(
            '${forecastTemperature[day]}°',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else if (weatherPicture == 'images/01d.png') {
      //sun
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            '${giveWeekday(convertEpochToDate(forecastDay[day]))}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 17.0,
            ),
          ),
          Image.asset(
            weatherPicture,
            width: 30.0,
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          Text(
            '${forecastTemperature[day]}°',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else if (weatherPicture == 'images/02d.png' ||
        weatherPicture == 'images/02n.png') {
      Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            '${giveWeekday(convertEpochToDate(forecastDay[day]))}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 17.0,
            ),
          ),
          Image.asset(
            weatherPicture,
            width: 30.0,
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          Text(
            '${forecastTemperature[day]}°',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            '${giveWeekday(convertEpochToDate(forecastDay[day]))}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 17.0,
            ),
          ),
          Image.asset(
            weatherPicture,
            width: 30.0,
            height: 30.0,
          ),
          Text(
            '${forecastTemperature[day]}°',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

However, the function claims that it has a return type of 'Widget' but does not end with a return statement. I am not really sure why this is the case as I have specifically ended it with an else condition just to ensure it always returns a widget. Furthermore, on certain cases, it crashes my app and tells me that an assertion has failed.

I am not really sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 2nd `else if` you forgot to use `return`

```
Widget adjustImage(String weatherPicture, int day) {
  if (weatherPicture == 'images/01n.png' || weatherPicture == 'images/13d.png' || weatherPicture == 'images/13n.png') {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          '${giveWeekday(convertEpochToDate(forecastDay[day]))}',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontSize: 17.0,
          ),
        ),
        Image.asset(
          weatherPicture,
          width: 15.0,
          height: 15.0,
        ),
        Text(
          '${forecastTemperature[day]}°',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  } else if (weatherPicture == 'images/01d.png') {
    //sun
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          '${giveWeekday(convertEpochToDate(forecastDay[day]))}',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontSize: 17.0,
          ),
        ),
        Image.asset(
          weatherPicture,
          width: 30.0,
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        Text(
          '${forecastTemperature[day]}°',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  } else if (weatherPicture == 'images/02d.png' ||
      weatherPicture == 'images/02n.png') {
    return Column( // you forgot to use return here
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          '${giveWeekday(convertEpochToDate(forecastDay[day]))}',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontSize: 17.0,
          ),
        ),
        Image.asset(
          weatherPicture,
          width: 30.0,
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        Text(
          '${forecastTemperature[day]}°',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  } else {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          '${giveWeekday(convertEpochToDate(forecastDay[day]))}',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            fontSize: 17.0,
          ),
        ),
        Image.asset(
          weatherPicture,
          width: 30.0,
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        Text(
          '${forecastTemperature[day]}°',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```